# How to set Content-Type for a form filed using 'multipart' in Go

Tags: go, multipartform-data

I am attempting to upload a file that requires me to set a specific Content-Type for the API. When I do this:

```
file, err := os.Open("helloWorld.wav")
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
audioFile, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("file", "helloWorld.wav")
_, err = io.Copy(audioFile, file)
if err != nil {
     return nil, 0, err
}
writer.Close()
```

It creates the multipart form properly, but assumes this content type:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I need to be able to set it to:

```
Content-Type: audio/wav;rate=8000
```

While of course I may set the headers for net/http, I am not seeing how to do this for individual fields in a multipart form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the source code [mime/multipart](http://golang.org/src/pkg/mime/multipart/writer.go) it's not possible, but you could implement something like this (note: it's not handling the escaping of filename correctly)

```
    func CreateAudioFormFile(w *multipart.Writer, filename string) (io.Writer, error) {
      h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
      h.Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`, "file", filename))
      h.Set("Content-Type", "audio/wav;rate=8000")
      return w.CreatePart(h)
}
```

Outputs

> --0c4c6b408a5a8bf7a37060e54f4febd6083fd6758fd4b3975c4e2ea93732
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="helloWorld.wav"
>   Content-Type: audio/wav;rate=8000
>   --0c4c6b408a5a8bf7a37060e54f4febd6083fd6758fd4b3975c4e2ea93732--

See [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/p5U_puIvkg) for full example.

Edit: To write the file data, also copy it to the writer as in the original example.

```
audioFile, _ := CreateAudioFormFile(writer2, "helloWorld.wav")
io.Copy(audioFile, file)
```

See [updated playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IrxRU7OZcc) for the full example that includes the file data.

Comment: That works well for setting the field. But it is not clear to me how you add the file contents in that newly created field using net/textproto.

Comment: Updated with details, exactly the same as how you initially did it.